# php global config and settings in application

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a file 'config.php' which Is included at the beginning of my program (see below)
Main file runs `require 'config.php';`

config.php

```
<?
global $config;
$config['tblist'] = 'pending'; 
$config['tbdone'] = 'checked';
$config['checkfreq'] = 24;
?>
```

I then create a new page object

```
$page = new Page($name,$source);
```

One of the functions in that page object I want to be able to grab stuff from the config but it doesn't seem to be able to reference to $config. Have I put global $config; in the right place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making references to global variables in functions, you must declare them as global:

`global $config;`

This is also interesting: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

> There is no way to declare a variable. Variables that don’t exist are
>   created with a null value when first used.
>
> Global variables need a global declaration before they can be used.
>   This is a natural consequence of the above, so it would be perfectly
>   reasonable, except that globals can’t even be read without an explicit
>   declaration—PHP will quietly create a local with the same name,
>   instead. I’m not aware of another language with similar scoping
>   issues.

To be fair it will also throw a Notice if you've got them enabled.

Comment: does it matter if the functions are in an object as above?

Comment: Any function will be outside the global scope, so you'll have to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Put `global $config` inside the function before using the variable.

See the PHP manual on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should in function declare $config is global variable

Maybe you need [PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

In the function that needs to use $config, did you first declare $config as global? For example:

```
function foo() {
    global $config;

    $a = $config['tblist'];
    ....
}
```

$config will only refer to the global variable if first declared as such, if not it will refer to a variable in the local scope.

You can find more details on globals here: [PHP Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can include $config from within your Page object:

```
class Page
{
    protected $config;
    public function __construct($configPath)
    {
        include $configPath;
        $this->config=$config;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also simply pass the `$config` array to the constructor